# RTSP live video streaming

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I'm building an application to live stream video from the raspberry pi to my android device. I have three functional ways of playing this stream:

[rtsp://media.smart-streaming.com/mytest/mp4:sample_phone_150k.mp4](http://rtsp://media.smart-streaming.com/mytest/mp4:sample_phone_150k.mp4)

1. Media Player + SurfaceView
2. VideoView
3. Intent.ACTION_VIEW

The problem is the application plays the above^ stream but doesn't play mine (rtsp://192.168.1.143:8554/vid.mp4) ... **but VLC does**.

I have tried streaming with VLC and with LIVE555 in multiple video formats and I've also tried playing a video that was recorded on the phone.

Here is my code:

```
//Stream methods 0 = MediaPlayer & SurfaceView, 1 = VideoView, 2 = Native Video Player
final int STREAM_USING = 0;

//MediaPlayer on surfaceView
String streamPath = "rtsp://192.168.1.143:8554/vid.mp4";//"rtsp://media.smart-streaming.com/mytest/mp4:sample_phone_150k.mp4";//"rtsp://192.168.1.143:8554/vid.mp4";//;"rtp://239.255.0.1:5004/";
Uri streamUri;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SurfaceView surfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

//VideoView
VideoView videoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //MediaPlayer
    switch (STREAM_USING) {
        case 0: {
            surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
            surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
            surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(800, 480);
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) {
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        //mediaPlayer.stop();
                        play();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BUFF : " + percent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                }
            });

            //Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            //i.setType("video/*");
            //startActivityForResult(i, 1234);
            streamUri = Uri.parse(streamPath);
            play();
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(streamPath));
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
            //mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.requestFocus();
            try {
                videoView.start();
            }
            catch (SecurityException se) {
                Log.e("SE", se.getMessage());
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(streamPath));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(streamPath));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

private void play() {
    try {
        //final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(streamPath);
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, streamUri);
        //mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });


    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        Log.e("SE", se.getMessage());
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, I've been trying for a week to get this to work with no success :(

Comment: what about provide logcat of android media api when u try to load that rtsp uri?? what is media player and or video view doing with it?

Comment: Ok, i will get back with it tomorrow

Comment: Sorry for the late reply:
RTP case:
`E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1, -1003)`
RTSP case:
`E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1, -2147483648)`

Comment: @ciprianoss : Do you need any good media player to play it? and are you sure that whatever you are trying to play is proper stream url and working in any browser properly?

Answer (score 8):

You already added two ways just i want to add bit modification. I have done streaming ralalted task.I have used rtsp with wowza.Few ways i'll let you know

try it once and let me know if you got issue.If your streaming in vlc working fine then something problem with app side. If these methods are not working then try with different phone. It also help you.

**1. Try with videoview**

```
vvVideoPlay = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvVideoPlay);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

String videoUrl = "rtsp://192.168.1.143:8554/vid.mp4";

    mediaController.setAnchorView(vvVideoPlay);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
    vvVideoPlay.setVideoURI(uri);
    vvVideoPlay.setMediaController(mediaController);
    vvVideoPlay.requestFocus();

    vvVideoPlay.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            mp.start();
            pdialog.dismiss();
            mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**2. Try with direct your phone player**

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.1.143:8554/vid.mp4")));
```

**3. Third way try to with this library with custom player in your app.**

**Step1.** Add it to your gradle

```
compile "fm.jiecao:jiecaovideoplayer:4.7.0"
```

**Step2.** Add it as your video play in xml layout.

```
<fm.jiecao.jcvideoplayer_lib.JCVideoPlayerStandard
    android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Step 3.** Check from here how to use this library in your class,

```
public class PlayVideoActivity extends BaseActivity {

@BindView(R.id.videoPlayer)
JCVideoPlayerStandard mVideoPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    restoreFromIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
public int getLayout() {
    return R.layout.activity_play_video;
}


// get video path from intent and play the video here
private void restoreFromIntent(Intent intent) {

    mVideoPlayer.setUp("rtsp://192.168.1.143:8554/vid.mp4"
            , JCVideoPlayerStandard.SCREEN_LAYOUT_LIST, "");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (JCVideoPlayer.backPress()) {
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    JCVideoPlayer.releaseAllVideos();
}
}
```

Hope this will help you to fix your problem.Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer, im gonna try it later today and see if it works. I dont think you understood something, i am able to play my stream with VLC but not with my own code, however the test link stream plays with my code.. in all cases.

Comment: yes i got it your point, so thats way i give you few tips.It help to figureout and easy to debug your code.

Comment: Ok, i'm currently trying an option I found today, then i will try out yours

Comment: yeah sure, if you got any issue then let me know.

Comment: please cross check your url which you are trying to play

Comment: im giving you the bounty because you are the only one who at least gave me an answer, i didnt get a chance to try it out yet, so i cant yet accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks buddy and do one  more thing. Remove .mp4 in rtsp stream then try